# interfacing HMC5883L compass I/O error

Tags: raspbian

I was running the first code given [here](http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/connecting-and-calibrating-hmc5883l.html) yesterday, i am using python 2.7 and raspberry pi model B 512MB RAM, raspbian OS HMC5883L with compass when i execute the code above i get an I/O error at lines 27 and 29 can you please help me fix this? And  is something wrong with my PI or Compass are they Ok?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i got it right, i should change
    `bus = smbus.SMBus(0)` to `bus = smbus.SMBus(1)`

 since i am using rev2 512 MB board.